# Converting Percent value to pixel in JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a string value in percent unit that will be assign to height but before assigning I need to deduct another height which got by top() the output result is `NaN`,  My code is as below:

```
var valHeight = "50%";
var result = valHeight - $("#item").css("top");
$("#AnotherItem").height(result);
```

as `valHeight` is string and percent and height is pixel the result will be `NaN`. How may I solve that issue? the `valHeight` is percent but top value is pixel. I need to have my result as percent
Let's clarify more:
I want to use calc function of CSS and I guess the below code is correct:

```
$('#AnotherItem').css('height', valHeight).css('height', '-='+itemOffsetTop);
```

the only problem is I want to use subtracted value in animate function.

Comment: Is there a method as `.top()` in jQuery?

Comment: Which one is the percent value?

Comment: valHeight is the percent value

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Please describe in words because your code (subtracting `.top()` from `50%`) really doesn't make sense as it isn't a legal operation and it isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues with your code:

1. `valHeight` is a string, not a number.  It needs to be a number before using it in a math operation.
2. It's also not clear where you're getting `.top()` from.  Perhaps you meant to use [`.offset().top`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)?

Example:

```
var valHeight = 50;
var result = valHeight - $("#item").offset().top;
$("#AnotherItem").height(result + "px");
```

---

Now, you modified your question to use `50%` and it doesn't really make sense.  If you want the result to be 50% of `$("#item").offset().top`, then you could use something like this:

```
var valHeight = 0.5;
var result = $("#item").offset().top * valHeight;
$("#AnotherItem").height(result + "px");
```

Comment: @Mehrdad - now your question doesn't really make sense (subtracting `.top` from 50%).  What do you want to accomplish?  Do you want the result to be `50%` of `$("#item").offset().top`?  If so, you would use `var result = $("#item").offset().top * 0.5;`

Comment: Actually 50% here is used for height.

Comment: @Mehrdad - we can't answer your question until you describe what you're trying to accomplish.  Your code as written is nonsensical so we need you to describe in words what you're trying to do and then we could probably help you quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

**First**

`valHeight` is a string you need to convert that to number.

```
var varlHeight = parseInt("50px");
```

**Second**

Your `$("#item").top()` is invalid, use this instead.

```
$("#item").offset().top
```

**Putting them together**

```
var valHeight=parseInt("50px");
var result= valHeight - $("#item").offset().top;
$("#AnotherItem").height(result);
```

**Update**

Since you've updated your post with a '50%' value. How about doing this kind of approach instead.

```
var valHeight="50%";
var itemOffsetTop = $("#item").offset().top;
$('#AnotherItem').css('height', valHeight).css('height', '-='+itemOffsetTop);
```

Comment: Please see updates. ValHeight value is in percent unit and top is pixel

Comment: What if I want to use value in animate function?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) as there is no method as `.top()` in jQuery

> Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

2. `valHeight` should be a number

*Code*

```
var valHeight = 50; //Or, parseInt("50px")
var result = valHeight - $("#item").offset().top;
$("#AnotherItem").height(result + "px");
```